# CSS responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

How to determine that the user has a desktop(portrait), not a phone(portrait) using CSS?
example: [responsive design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEJyu.png)

Comment: See [`pointer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/pointer).

Comment: Is there some capability of the device that you want to test for? For example, that is has a 'pointing device' as @SebastianSimon suggests or something else? I suppose I'm asking 'how do you define a phone; how do you define a desktop?'

Answer (score 0):

do you mean to change the design according to the desktop or phone? If that is the case then we can simply use:

```css
.abc{
    padding: 0;
    color: blue;
    background-color: aqua;

}

@media(max-width: 780px)
{
  .abc{
         margin-left:20px;
         padding:30px;
         background-color:red;
         color: black;
   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="abc">Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

we can also use min-width:....; for the devices having any px of min width.

Comment: A desktop may have a small, portrait window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query for that

**Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up)**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {...}
```

**Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up)**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {...}
```

**Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up)**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {...}
```

**Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up)**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {...}
```

Comment: These tests don't tell you whether the user is on a phone or a desktop. They indicate the size range of the viewport.